# How to remove unwanted space below scrollview in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, scrollview

When I run this code on my device, additional space appears below the imageView. In the end, I would like my images to fulfill the greatest amount of space on the screen without distorting their dimensions. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have attached the code for my elements and their attributes. Thanks!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_ch0_example_problems"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:fillViewport="false"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
tools:context="com.example.android.chsalgebra.Ch0ExampleProblems">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/prevBut1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:onClick="displayProblemMinus"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="Previous"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#769ecd" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextBut1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:onClick="displayProblemPlus"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#769ecd" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/prevBut1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/prevBut1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/prevBut1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ex1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ch0ex1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up playing around with attributes and I found that android:adjustViewBounds set to true fixed my problem. I don't know exactly this attribute does, but it worked! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the imageview with text view with height wrap content.

If the space is still there, then the problem is with the scroll view, else imageview has problem.

Comment: I can't do this because I am displaying images? Maybe I'm misunderstanding you...

Comment: I suggest it for testing which object has programatically wrong,  scroll view or image view. This suggestion only for testing purpose. You can set image view after problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

you can set the ImageView`XML (android:scaleType="centerInside or fitCenter")

Comment: centerInside and fitCenter just move the image down and creates a space above and below the image.